# Auto adjust my background image size

Tags: html, css

I've been googling for awhile and none of the answers seem to match my need, need someone to help me with this, thanks.

my personal website is: http://simonykhsu.com for refrences

my code for the background image is

```
<div class="landing-header" style="background-image: url('skitrip_owlshead.jpg');">
```

[image]

i've tried implementing this background image code but i cant find the section in css file to make the background go skin color

```
<div id="image-container">
         <img id="image" src="skitrip_owlshead.jpg" alt="middle"/>
    </div>
```

[image: this is what it looks like]

and also the second code above doesnt seem to bring my image to the middle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for centering the image and set  backgroud color you can do this in the image-container div

```
<div id="image-container" style="text-align:center; background-color:#ccc;">
     <img id="image" src="skitrip_owlshead.jpg" alt="middle"/>
</div>
```

`#ccc` is a sample color ... you set with your color code..

Comment: how do i readjust the size of the image? it is a bit too big in my opinion

Comment: Try Defining the maxHeight and maxWidth (in px)  of the container

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but I don't really understand what it is that you're trying to accomplish.

Couple of heads-ups tho:

- its better to create a seperate CSS file, instead of using inline-styling. Make a file called style.css and put your CSS in that. Put this in the `<head>` section of your website:

  ```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
  ```
- The `alt="middle"` is the alt-text. It's not used for styling
  (centering) your image, but to describe your image. Something like
  "skiteam owlshead team" should be good.

If you want to center the image and put 'skin color' right and left to it, put this in your style.css:

```
#image-container {
background-color: #FFFCF5;
}

#image-container img {
text-align:center;
}
```